# Netty (Dummy) for existing service

Tags: java, sockets, netty

There is an existing service that i would like to write a dummy service (using Netty) for. It will be used for testing purposes.

The existing client code fragment for the service looks like:

```
Socket socket = new java.net.Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080), 10000);
socket.setSoTimeout(20000); // set a timeout of 20 seconds
InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
// write some string to the server and wait for answer
out.println("SomeCommand");
// server has written some answer, read it
char[] c = new char[2];
ir.read(c, 0, 2);
String cs = new String(c);
if ("OK".equals(cs.toString())) {
    // write some more string's to the server
}
// we're done, close the connection
out.println("BYE");
out.close();
socket.close();
```

Is [Netty](http://netty.io/) the right framework to create a server for java.net.Socket connections? (If not, which framework should be used, if any?)

I am trying to find a way to start with Netty using the QuoteOfTheMoment example. The QuoteOfTheMomentServerHandler does basically what i want, upon the incoming message, return some answer so that the above snippet can read the answer using the inputstream but the above socket cannot make a connection to the QuoteOfTheMomentServer. The error is "connection refused".

[**EDIT**] More clarification:
The problem (i think) is not connecting or the port i use. Let me try to better ask the question:

I just started with netty (no nio experience) and am not familiar with the different types of channels, pipelines and what not.
The server should, **like** a servlet request/response (like, not http or trying to rebuild a http servlet impl), react on a inputString written to the output-stream as in the code fragment and write back some string/bytes to the input-stream as in the code fragment, so the client only then moves on. So the connection should stay open but also be synchronous, the client waits for answer from the server. If i use the example ["Writing the Server Side of a Socket" in the java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) i am able to get it working for the client. But i want to utilize the thread handling  etc. from netty.
The QuoteOfTheMomentServerHandler seems as server side implementation what i want but can that setup handle the given client code ?

So the question is which kind of pipeline, channel or something like that should be used given the way the client works ?

Again, the client and server are existing. I want to build a dummy server implementation to work with the existing client.

Answer (score 1):

Netty is a TCP/IP framework. So yes if you are developing a TCP/IP server this toolkit is good to use.

I assume you are getting a error when trying to connect the client to the server. Also the server should also be running.

When getting a the connection refused error there are a couple of thine to check. First one is the firewall(if any) on the server allowing connections to port 8080? Secondly from your client machine try open a telnet session to the server something like:

```
Telnet yourserverip 8080
```

This opens a socket connection to the server. If you get a error message Google it.

The last one is that you might be running a server like tomcat, glassfish, IIS which uses port 8080 already. Try a non standard port like 10810 for example.

UPDATES:

If you are new to netty please read the users guide found here http://netty.io/docs/stable/guide/html/.

I had a look at the Quote of the moment service and I do believe I found part of the problem. The Quote of the moment service is a broadcast UDP/IP client and server. UDP is a much more lightweight "version" of TCP IP. It does not guarantee delivery to the client or server and it is broadcast. UDP is sort of like a radio broadcast as it is generally not targeted to a specific IP but broadcast over the entire network. Thus you normal TCP IP connection will not be able to work on the UDP server.

See this link on how to write a UDP Client http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/.

I would suggest that you convert the Quote of the moment server from UDP to TCP/IP server as this will give you some practise in creating a TCP/IP server without getting into too much detail. Once you are comfortable with that you should be able to start once from scratch.

Just remember that Netty handles the NIO part for you. It is a higher level framework based on NIO thus hiding a lot of the detail from you. You dont need to know NIO that well to use netty but you need to understand the Netty concepts well.

Comment: +1.  Also make sure you're listening on the right interface. For best results, I always use "0.0.0.0"  (all interfaces) but it's all too easy to mistakenly listen on "localhost" and then you can't connect from a remote.

Comment: Thanks @Namphibian for your response. I probably didn't formulate my question correct. I hope the question is clear now.  I don't run the server in some sort of a container. It should be a standalone running process. Testing right now, all is running in standalone programs on my local machine.

Comment: The netty project has decent documentation that I suggest reading. Since I don't have access to your current client it is going to be difficult to tell you how to setup the server. However since you mentioned the quote of the moment server is more or less what you want I would study that example and use it as a framework for your server. The only way to really get to grips with any framework is to understand the concepts then start prototyping. The learning curve for netty is not that bad. Go ahead take the plunge.

Comment: You can find the user guide for netty http://netty.io/docs/stable/guide/html/ here. It is a simple and gentle introduction to netty.

Comment: I've read the netty doc's a couple of times and tried some examples but it doesn't became clear to me which channel or pipe implementation i should use. Actually i don't have more time to really try and trouble shoot everything. Using the above mentioned sample on the java tutorial site i now have a working server dummy. 
So, i'm afraid that my question is not answered but thanks anyway for the effort.

Comment: WHat difficulties are you still facing? You say that the dummy server is now working?